# SVN Automated Replication

Tags: svn, version-control, version

We've recently set up Subversion on our CentOS server.  Our end goal is to complete all of our work on a development subdomain which has its own repository.  Once we are satisfied on whatever we are doing, we would like to replicate the development repository into the 'live code' repository automatically.

I've read up on post-commit hooks, but I don't want all commits to the development repo to automatically be moved to the live repo.  Unfortunately, our head guy is not comfortable with everyone having root access to run the SVN replicate command through the console.  Otherwise, this wouldn't be an issue.

Is it possible to create a script that could be run from the web to run the svn replicate command?  Or can the post-commit hook script be written in such a way that we can specify when to replicate to the live server?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: i know this isnt the answer youre looking for, but have you considered moving to something like git where this sort of operation is more natural?

Comment: For SVN it would be more natural to have single repository and a branch inside of it which goes to deployment. In this way you will have all information available to developers - what was deployed, when, by whom and which changes were included into that deployment.

Comment: Most people use branches for scenarios like this, not separate repositories.